# What is the code used to redirect to mobile site and where does it go?

Tags: mobile, redirect, desktop

here is my what I am trying to do.

I have a .mobi site wayfieldfoods.mobi that is set up on a wordpress format. I am using a plugin that make the site mobile with custom menu wayfieldfoods.mobi/mlp/home.

my clients website is wayfieldfoods.com . How do I add (or redirect)  wayfieldfoods.mobi to my clients site? if someone is using a mobile device and types in the url wayfieldfoods.com, I want the mobi site to display instead of the regular wayfieldfoods.com desktop site.

I spoke with someone earlier and they said that it's a code that has to be installed on the index page of my clients wayfieldfoods.com website in order for mobile access to the mobi site.

What is the special code needed to redirect to mobile traffic to my wayfieldfoods.mobi site.

(as a side note wayfieldfoods.mobi shows up on a desktop computer as a regular wordpress site with the default twenty eleven theme, but wayfieldfoods.mobi displays on a mobile phone with the mobile friendly website I set up. It works fine displayed on a mobile phone).

Comment: the "special code" is something to look at the provided  browser user agent string, and/or some javascript to do some heuristics to figure out if it's a mobile platform, and does an HTTP redirect if it is mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handset Detection](http://www.handsetdetection.com) to redirect mobiles to your mobile site (disclaimer : my startup). Browse on over and create a free account. There's a javascript snippet you paste into the  of your homepage.

Hope that helps.